# Redirecting from Http to Https with AWS's ELB in Chrome and FireFox

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, http-redirect, amazon-elb

I have setup redirecting from http to https at AWS with ELB. The procedure is as follow.

In the file .htaccess, put the following X-Forwarded-Proto code

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^ELB-HealthChecker
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
</VirtualHost>
```

Then the .htaccess file is put inside the folder my website's index.php stays.

I tested at Chrome, FireFox and Safari.
Both Chrome and Safari work, but FireFox doesn't.

At both Chrome and Safari, when I key in www.domainname.com at browser, I see the change in the browser as https://www.domainname.com. Same to Safari as well.

But in Chrome, when I key in www.domainname.com, the page is loaded with http://www.domainname.com. Even I keyed in as http://www.domainname.com, it is by itself changed to https://www.domainname.com.

What could be wrong? Is that redirecting still doesn't work at FireFox?

Comment: YesI cleared browser cache for a few times already. FireFox still the same.

Comment: The browser doesn't show me it is unsecure. But I don't see https at the front yet.

Comment: I got a reply from AWS for a clue is that ELB just insert the redirection info using X-Forwarded-Proto. So actual implementation of redirection needs to be happened in the instance, in the apache. I need to figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am solving the issue for a long time and now can make it works successfully.
I like to share what I have done as follows.

```
(1)Create .htaccess file inside the folder same as root file index.php exists
(2).htaccess file has
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
(3)Then enable mod_rewrite, try the command line command: 
   sudo a2enmod rewrite
(4)To make sure mod_rewrite is enabled, update /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file as
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
initially was 
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

Then you can setup http to https successfully
You need to restart server as sudo service apache2 restart after update of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```